# Is there a way to integrate Mercurial with Zend studio 5?

Tags: mercurial, zend-studio

My php dev team is using Zend Studio 5
We are about to start using a version control system and are seriously considering Mercurial - but after searching the web for a while, I can't find any solutions to integrate Mercurial with Zend 5.
I have a feeling that if the version control won't integrate with the IDE, then it will be too complicated / annoying to use.
So, anyone know a solution for this?

Alternatively, I am open to a suggestion for a lightweight IDE that integrates Mercurial and even better, a task/bug reporting system - all in one.

Thanks!

note - this version of Zend does not run on Eclipse, and therefore MercurialEclipse plugin cannot be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for someone who is used to using an IDE, the most annoying thing about all of the popular free version control systems is that they are command line based (at least out-of-the-box).

But there is a solution for that:
Every VCS out there has at least one decent GUI (Mercurial has [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.org), for example), so you can use one of these to avoid typing the commands by hand.

Now for the IDE integration:
Yes, an integration into the IDE of your choice would be even more comfortable than just starting a separate program (TortoiseHG) for your VCS GUI.
But when there is a GUI available for your VCS, do you really need IDE integration as well?

I can only speak for myself, but I'm using TortoiseHG for nearly two years now (at work and at home), I never used IDE integration and I **never** missed it.
(my co-workers all use TortoiseHG without IDE integration as well)

I don't know if it's possible to integrate Mercurial with Zend Studio.
But I would suggest that you at least try to use TortoiseHG without integration first, and see if you can't just live with that.

Answer (score 0):

[MercurialEclipse](http://javaforge.com/project/HGE) works for Zend Studio 9... I'm not sure about older versions though.